# load testing on form page

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

Let's assume if I am doing 1000 users load testing using jmeter and blazemeter on a form page (survey form) is there any way those 1000users can reflect on submission page

I was getting entry on only one user

---

[if this is the from i am filling and recording it with the help of blazeMeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uccgz.png)

[And I am only getting reflection of one user on the backend after load testing 1000users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqbtF.jpg)

[This is how it's looking in jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiswH.jpg)

[what should I do so there will 1000 reflection of different id in my backend]

Answer (score 1):

If you recorded your request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) - you will have:

- 1 selected option
- 1 login

If you want to properly simulate 1000 different users you should:

1. Ensure that your [JMeter test is configured to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)
2. Ensure that each JMeter virtual user has its own username and password (or whatever is the way of identifying the user), the most commonly used test element for parameterization is [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
3. It would also be a good idea to use different survey options for each user, you can either use the aforementioned CSV Data Set Config for this for pre-defined test data or if you prefer random - check out [HTML Link Parser](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Link_Parser) and [Poll Example](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#poll_example)